# Плотная компановка элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блоки расположенные так что бы занимать всё пространство блока.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно и нужно использовать что бы добиться такого результата. Без ручного расположения элементов и задавания им координат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону библиотеки [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)
Без js такую сетку динамической не сделать. Если нет задачи сделать так, чтобы она адаптировалась под случайный контент, то можно использовать css grid.